# Jenkins: How to access copied artifact?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to execute a jar file built in a different jenkins job. For that I use the CopyArtifact plugin.

Copying the artefact seems to work. The following code

```
step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
                  projectName: '/BuildJob/master',
                  filter: 'target/mytool.jar',
                  target: './']);
```

finishes with

```
Copied 1 artifact from "BuildJob » master" build number 1
```

But how can I access this copied jar file? I tried the following:

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: "java -jar mytool.jar")
```

but this ended up in the following error message:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile mytool.jar
```

Comment: you file which was copied from other job will reside in your executing build workspace, you can directly provided java -jar mytool.jar in jenkins execute shell

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried that, but the error message is still the same: The jar file cannot be accessed/found.

Comment: OK, found my problem: The path was wrong. Correct: java -jar **/mytool.jar